# Split field across hyphen

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I split a combined field from my table into two separate report fields, based on the position of a hyphen character?

For example, I'd like to separate `3434-4567` into two separate columns - one for `3434`, and one for `4567`.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn this number into a string, the rest is cake. Create two new formula fields, named `Column1` and `Column2`

```
LEFT(CSTR({YourFieldHere}), INSTR(1, {YourFieldHere}, "-") - 1)
```

---

```
RIGHT(CSTR({YourFieldHere}), INSTR(1, {YourFieldHere}, "-") + 1)
```